# writing unsorted mf4 file using asammdf

Tags: asammdf

Does asammdf offer the possibility to write unsorted mf4 files? I have seen that it can read both unsorted and sorted mf4 files

If it is possible do you know where I can find a short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asammdf library always writes sorted files